# How to add a new column to CSV according to certain equality of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, comparison

Here is my question. I am working with a python CSV data set using pandas. I am comparing crime rates in NYC neighborhoods and Airbnb rents in that neighborhood using 2 different data sets. What I want to do is checking if the neighborhood names are same then adding the crime rate column next to the price column of air BnB df. However, the indexes are not same such that there are 500  crimes for the upper east side houses while there is only 1 crime number for upper east side. So how can I combine this info? HELP much needed as I have a report due by tonight thnx

So far I have done:
i only implemented csv files as df for both and then thought about creating a dctionary with crime rates data for neighbourhoods and rates and if I find equality on aribnb locations and dictionary locations i want to add crime rate values from dictionary to an empty list. And after doing this I believe list will be in ordered way with Air bnb locations so that I can add this list as a new column to Air bnb csv. Sorry my code is not proper so ı cant post it here. Also I am stuck at adding the proper value of dict to empty list by finding same locations in 2 csvs.

datasets:
http://app.coredata.nyc/?mlb=false&ntii=crime_all_rt&ntr=Community%20District&mz=14&vtl=https%3A%2F%2Fthefurmancenter.carto.com%2Fu%2Fnyufc%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Fviz%2F98d1f16e-95fd-4e52-a2b1-b7abaf634828%2Fviz.json&mln=true&mlp=true&mlat=40.718&ptsb=&nty=2018&mb=roadmap&pf=%7B%22subsidies%22%3Atrue%7D&md=table&mlv=false&mlng=-73.996&btl=Borough&atp=neighborhoods

https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data

Comment: Please provide your solution/code so that people can help/comment.

Comment: out = pd.merge(df1,df2, on="neiberhood_name")